# Decreasing Forward FX rate curve

Tags: yield-curve, forward, currency

i've constructed a Forward FX curve using the formula:
$F= Spot \frac{(1+I_b*n/N)}{(1+I_c*n/N)}$
when i get these Forward rates for 1 month, 3, 6 till 1 year i got a decreasing forward Fx Curve 
How to explain that

Regards

Comment: Please properly format your post and explain the notation you use. Why should the curve not be downward sloping? If a currency pair A/B has an upward sloping forward curve then the pair B/A has a downward sloping one.

Comment: Make sure you have the units and the interest rates the right way around. For example if the currency is USDJPY (i.e. how many yen it takes to make a dollar), then in the numerator should be the JAPAN interest rate and in the denominator should be the USA interest rate. For EURUSD, $i_{USD}$ in the numerator and $i_{EUR}$ in the denominator.